# MAX function returning unexpected result

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, max

I am using this query and result is not as expected:

```
select max(time_taken) 
from abc 
where id='13' 
  and tdy_date='2017-10-13'
```

Result:

```
9:53
```

But actual result should be 10:03. The data type of `time_taken` is `character varying` and it is in 00:00 format.

Comment: Why do you store a time in a `varchar`? That should be a `time` column. Convert it to the proper data type and then this will work, e.g. `max(time_taken::time)`

Comment: Same as a_horse_with_no_name, however, If you have to use character varying, use a standard format i.e `09:53` and `10:03`. Ideally you may also wish to confirm that you're using 24 hour system.

Comment: why not just casting it to time?.. `select greatest('9:53'::time,'10:03'::time), greatest('9:53'::text,'10:03'::text);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use data type as date time but for the time you can get required result using this query

```
select max(time_taken::time) as max from abc where student_id='13' and tdy_date='2017-10-13';
```

Answer (score -1):

Because all the values in the time_taken column are 00:00 format, and so long as they are in 24 hour notation (i.e. 00:00 to 23:59), it's no problem to alter the data type of the column to TIME, just execute the following line of code:

```
 ALTER TABLE abc ALTER COLUMN time_taken TIME
```

This way when you select the Max time_taken, SQL Server is able to properly prioritise the values. So:

```
SELECT MAX(LEFT(time_taken,5))
FROM abc
WHERE id='13'
AND tdy_date='2017-10-13'
```

Should now give: 10:03.

It would give 10:03:00.0000000 but I used the LEFT function to select only the first five characters from the left side of the string.